# how to recompile kernel iptables by enabling tproxy

Tags: transparent-proxy

I'm new to the Kernel iptables/netfilter.
   I'm having red hat linux with Linux Kernel 2.6.37-rc1,iptables 1.4.10 ,squid 3.1. But my iptables are not configured with tproxy table. Now, i want to recompile the netfilter/iptables module alone to enable the tproxy. can any body help me out a step by step procedure to enable the tproxy in my system..

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to setup squid as transparent proxy, you can get away with the default DNAT and REDIRECT targets. No need for recompiling.